# Continuous Console.log() s in home page

Tags: bug, status-completed, homepage

I visited the homepage of stackoverflow.com for the first time (without login state) and opened the console. Then I saw that something is continuously logging on the console so I think it may be a bug:

[image]

Comment: Amateurs!  ... ;) .. that is what you get when you're allowed to hack some inline JavaScript directly into the html to get your stuff passed Nick Craver without a code review and straight into production ....

Comment: @rene pls. don't be so hard on them! If they get scared by your remark, they will ban console logs entirely in the developer team, causing frustration. I don't mean this with overtones, but literally. Console logs had helped me immensely. I know, learning a debugger could help even more immensely; the real way of working. I also agree that console.log() outputs don't belong in production. But this is not an organization that should be poked with scary remarks; they easily get too scared, and that can cause damage that no-one intended... (Let's save the confrontation for worthwhile causes.)

Comment: @Levente I'm not the one that scares them. Nick is capable to do that on his own. I'm pretty sure once he is finished there will be no more console.log statements in production and I'm also sure the team will have had a learning opportunity. I poke at organizations for a living, no-one died (yet) due to my poking.

Comment: Pity I am not a web-dev to laugh at SO team and SO teams..

Answer (score 12):

`logos start 4`

Well, at least it wasn't an [alert(false)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71780/lol-debugging-are-we-stack-overflow-homepage-alerts-false) this time...

`logos end 8`

Comment: Is there any chance that we'll get to know what the 4 and the 8 means? :)

Comment: @Scratte I'm not entirely sure (wasn't my code), but looks like it was some sort of debugging for the number of logos on the page: `console.log("logos start", logosShown * logosCurrentPage); console.log("logos end", (logosShown * logosCurrentPage) + logosShown);`

Comment: will the culprit [get a badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71810/786798)? :)